# Apache2 : redirect subfolder to https (http://example.com/sub -> https://example.com/sub)

Tags: ssl-certificate, http, redirect, https, apache2

I'm setting up an `Apache2` server on `Ubuntu 16.04`.

I use a self-signed certificate because I want my `nextcloud` instance to be available **only with** `https`. For now, I use a permanent redirection :

```
#/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Redirect permanent "/" "https://example.com/"
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

I followed [that guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04) for setting up a self-signed certificate.

However, I would like to publish files in a public html directory, let's say `example.com/files` and make them available through `http`, so that users doesn't need to trust my self-signed certificate.

What changes do I need to do in apache configuration to achieve that goal, if it can be done ?

### Expected result :

- `example.com/nextcloud`  : available **only** with https
- `example.com/html`      : directory and sub directories available with http

  - `example.com/files`
  - `example.com/files/papers`

### local directories:

```
/var/www/nextcloud
/var/www/html
/var/www/html/index.html
/var/www/html/files
```

### apache2ctl -S output

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
*:443                  example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:2)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

#### **EDIT :**

With rewrite mode enabled, I've try to add [this](http://adamdoupe.com/blog/2010/10/27/redirecting-a-folder-to-https-with-apaches-config-on-ubuntu/) inside `sites-available/000-default.conf`, but it doesn't work :

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/nextcloud/.\*
 RewriteRule ^(.\*)$ https://example.com$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Why bother with a self-signed certificate, then?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Because I would like to connect to owncloud with SSL

Comment: So use a real certificate!

Comment: How would that solve my issue ?

Comment: You said it: "so that users doesn't need to trust my self-signed certificate."

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it. Maybe my question isn't clear, I'm not a native english speaker, sorry. What I want to do is to configure apache so that I have distinct access type to distinct web folders on my server, owncloud is just a example. Some should be available via SSL, forcing HTTPS, others should be available without and therefore accessible via HTTP only. I thought that it could be done using some kind of redirection in Virtualhosts, but I have no clue how.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would do something like (this is completely untested):

```
#/etc/apache2/sites-available/010-http_example.com

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName example.com
    <Location /files>
      ....
    </Location>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/files/?
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```